# How many peaks would there be in H1 NMR of ethene?

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy, symmetry

Since the bonds can't rotate, would there be 2 peaks? Likewise, how many peaks would there be in *trans*-but-2-ene and *cis*-but-2-ene?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to consider whether the protons in ethene are chemically equivalent, magnetically equivalent, or both. The lewis structure of ethene:

[image: Lewis structure of ethene]

Because of the *symmetry* of the planar ethene molecule, all H atoms are chemically and magnetically equivalent. The spin system is therefore **A$_4$**. The signal is *not* split because the environment is the same for all H atoms. The signal would therefore be a single peak. Compared to an "average" methyl group, the ethylene protons are less shielded, and would appear at a higher chemical shift than methyl groups.